# Are LinkedLists an unintuitive solution since most of the time I don't need to know the physical location of an element in a Collection?

Tags: java, linked-list

Recently a coworker showed me some code he had written with a LinkedList and I couldn't get my head around it.

a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f

If I want to get d from the LinkedList, don't I have to traverse the list starting with a and iterating up to d or starting with f and iterating back to d?

**Why would I care WHERE d is stored physically in the Collection?**

Comment: That's a poor question title.  I can't find any connection between "unintuitive" and "physical element".  Could you please rephrase the title to clarify your question.  This is really quite difficult to parse.  What do you want to know?

Comment: but is getting d more important than inserting g? or more important than deleting b? because with out answering those questions you can't know what structure would suit your needs. it might be that fetching is a bit more expensive but if you only do that 1 time for every 1k inserts why would you care about fetching speed compared to inserting speed?

Comment: In particular, if you iterate over the list (which is really one of the most common things to do with a collection), it really isn't any slower than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every linked list is linked in both directions but, normally, yes. This type of collection  features sequential access in the forward or forward and reverse directions.

The advantages are:

- least amount of memory overhead except for a flat array
- very fast insert and delete
- memory can be allocated and released one element at a time
- easy to implement (not so important with modern languages but it was important in C89 and C99)
- LIFO or FIFO ordering is possible

Comment: The list as diagramed is "singly linked" so you can only travel in one direction (forward).. with a "dual linked" list you can travel both directions. a<->b<->c<->d<->e<->f  BUT you store twice as many pointers and have to keep both pointers in sync when adding/deleting.  Note that you can HOLD a link to any point on the list ( mypointer->d ) but have no guarantee that the item is still ON the list unless you traverse it.  Just know that LinkedList is (in general) slower to traverse than, for example, ArrayList but quicker to insert/delete.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the right question is not WHERE, but HOW it stored your collection. According to this, your time of adding, searching, deleting and keeping your collection consistent is different. So, when you choose your type collection you should keep in mind, what will be the most frequent operation and pick the best solution for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Linked lists typically have better performance characteristics than arrays for adding and removing elements.

And yes, if you're operating on sorted data, you do normally care what order elements are stored in.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't care, regardless of whether you're using a LinkedList or an ArrayList.  LinkedLists offer the advantage of being able to easily add elements to the beginning of a list, which you can't do with an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are not about "physical locations" (whatever you mean by that), lists are a certain data structure that can grow and shrink and provide decent complexity across the various operations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly traverse the linked list, as `LinkedList` offers [`indexOf(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) and [`get(int)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)). These will still traverse the list, but will do it implicitly.

You'll care about how a collection orders items because this affects efficiency of operations on the collection, particularly insert, fetch & removal. Any ordering on the items in a collection also affect timing of algorithms that use the data structure.